# Why would my internet speed increase when connected through UPS?

Tags: internet, ups, speedtest

The past few places I've lived over the years I've noticed a strange phenomenon: when I have my coaxial cable internet connection passing through the coaxial on my UPS and then into my modem, the internet speed results from a speed test get a noticeable bump. My current plan is for 60mbps down, but after passing through the UPS I'm 'getting' 70mbps down. I've seen even bigger jumps when I was on a faster internet plan at a former residence.

I've wondered if it's a just incorrect reporting, but I expect popular speed test websites would have accounted for that by now. Is it possible my ISP is giving me extra juice because it's perceiving a congestion because of the UPS passthrough? I'm not complaining after all, just always been curious.